# Where can i try searching the module "File_styles"?

Tags: 7

I have installed the media module for drupal 7 but it requests me the installation of a module I cannot find File_Styles.
Where can I searching this module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[File Styles](http://drupalcode.org/project/styles.git/tree/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/contrib/file_styles) is a module that is part of the [Styles](http://drupal.org/project/styles) project.